# sending messages beteewn Two entities Doctrine2 (User and Company )

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping

I have two entities (user and Company). I must set up an mail system, each user can send messages to another user or to a company, and the same for the the companie.and i have to displays messages exchanged in form of conversation. can I implement this with Doctrine2 and Symfony2?

Answer (score 0):

Explaining the whole structure on how to do it is a little bit to complicated...BUT

I think what you looking for is a usable data-structure... and for this you will need a manyToMany relation with extra columns, please take a look at the following links I hope this will give you an idea on how to manage your data:

http://future500.nl/articles/2013/09/doctrine-2-how-to-handle-join-tables-with-extra-columns/
http://future500.nl/articles/2013/09/more-on-one-to-manymany-to-one-associations-in-doctrine-2/

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. thank you